# Drupal, jQuery -> Slidorion and Views

Tags: jquery, drupal, slider, field

I am actualy trying to integrate the Slidorion Slider (http://www.slidorion.com/) in a Drupal View.
At the moment i am stuck to add my View fields to the slidorion code:

```
<div id="slidorion">
    <div id="slider">
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
        <div class="slide"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="accordion">
        <div class="link-header">New Features</div>
        <div class="link-content">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
        <div class="link-header">A Simple Image</div>
        <div class="link-content">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
        <div class="link-header">Background Image w/ HTML</div>
        <div class="link-content">
            <!-- content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is, that I dont know how to print a special array value of a field. In pseudo code it should look like something like that:

```
<div id="slidorion">
    <div id="slider">
        <div class="slide">[field_image_0]</div>
        <div class="slide">[field_image_1]</div>
        <div class="slide">[field_image_2]</div>
    </div>

    <div id="accordion">
        <div class="link-header">[field_title_0]</div>
        <div class="link-content">
            [field_content_0]
        </div>
        <div class="link-header">[field_title_1]</div>
        <div class="link-content">
            [field_content_1]
        </div>
        <div class="link-header">[field_title_2]</div>
        <div class="link-content">
            [field_content_2]
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Anyone got a idea how to solve this?